# Cannot open the file created with O_CREAT

Tags: c, file-io

I created a file with the flag `O_CREAT`, but when I tried to open the created "out.txt" with Notepad. It said "cannot open this file" or something like "access denied".

```
fd = open("out.txt", O_CREAT);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must close your file using `close`-call. Otherwise its contents won't be flushed and the file not written to disk. Besides you might be telling what you want to do on the file.

```
fd = open("out.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT); //write to the file
//write to file
close(fd); //might check return value
```

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_%28system_call%29) on this.